# Qt Quick FolderListModel implementation for .svg files runtime warnings/errors

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

In directory `/images` I have several .svg files (vector graphics files created with Adobe Illustrator 17 and Corel Draw X7) that I want to load into Qt Quick Application (Qt 5.4.1 for Linux 64bit) using `FolderListModel` model that will bi shown in some `ListView`. Here is the code:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2

import Qt.labs.folderlistmodel 2.1

ApplicationWindow
{
    id: ueMainWindow

    visible: true

    width: 1920
    height: 1080

    color: "black"

    title: qsTr("eTestApp")

    property string ueRootDirectory:"/images"
    property real ueImagesLoadProgress;
    property bool ueImageLoading;

    ListView
    {
        id: ueImagesListView

        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height

        FolderListModel
        {
            id: ueImageModel

            folder: "file://"+ueRootDirectory
            nameFilters: ["*.svg"]
        }

        Component
        {
            id: ueImageDelegate

            Image
            {
                source: ueImageModel.folder + "/" + fileName
            }
        }

        model: ueImageModel
        delegate: ueImageDelegate
    }

}
```

When I run project that contains this code with `QtCreator`, I get for every .svg file inside `/images` directory following error:

```
file:///images/filename.svg:1:1: Expected token `numeric literal'
file:///images/filename.svg:1:1: Expected a qualified name id
```

`filename.svg` represents name of file for every file in `/images` directory. What does that mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK Loader is only to load QML Components, not to load svg files.
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-loader.html#details

If you want to load svg files you can use **Image** instead
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-image.html

And you can use **filePath** or **fileURL** instead of doing **ueImageModel.folder + "/" + fileName** 
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt-labs-folderlistmodel-folderlistmodel.html

Comment: thanks, but that is not issue here, I've even corrected code to MWE, I just want to know what those warnings/errors mean.

Comment: @MarkoFrelih The errors are quick compiler trying to understand what's in your svg file, it tries to compile it as a qml file, but of course, it's not possible. (as Loader is to load qml components)

Comment: but why is compiler trying to compile them, I do not haven them anywhere declared in project, they are being loaded into `ListView` through `FolderListModel`?

Comment: You were loading it using Loader, Loader tries to load a qml file, to load a qml file it needs to compile it: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-loader.html#details

Comment: aaaa the previous code, yes, you are right! Thank you, now I understand!